# Sphinx ignore ID from result if Match

Tags: python, sphinx

I am showing some recommended product to the user and If the user ignores any product from the list that product should not appear in the result. But in my case ignore result appears and the rest of unignored rest gone

below is my code:

```
MATCH('@!objectid (%s)' % '|'.join(ids_str))
```

Answer (score 1):

The ! on the field selector is meaning to search all fields EXCEPT that field. ie `@!` means 'ignore field'. (`@` on its own is only field)

So your query is looking for any of the ids in any field *other* than objectid.

Probably want

```
MATCH('@objectid -(%s)' % '|'.join(ids_str))
```

To negate the keywords, not the field!

---

Although sphinx doesn't like running queries that ONLY consist of negative keywords, so might need something else. Another keyword that matches ALL documents.

Kinda like

```
MATCH('the @objectid -(%s)' % '|'.join(ids_str))
```

as in most documents may contain `the`. But to be sure to catch all, might need some other synthetic value, that you can guarantee is in every document! (if you don't have some other keywords to match!)

Comment: I thought using "!" Is only enough to ignore the term without @ .  Well done.